# Approve Workflow in SharePoint Online (O365)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, office-365, designer-workflow

Is there a way to do a SharePoint Workflow which can approve a document?

The recipient should just get a notification (through mail) and should be able to click "approve" or "not approve" somehow.

It this possible with the SharePoint Workflow functionalities?

Comment: That means approve/reject button should be mail body?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be also in the document itself.